# Add public Github repo to Julia as a package

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and Github. I'm playing a package called CellFishing.jl.(https://github.com/bicycle1885/CellFishing.jl ) When I tried to install CellFishing.jl as the instructions on the website, Julia requested private key location at git@github.com. I don't know how to fix it.  Please help me if u know. Thanks. I'm using MacBook Air M2.

I pasted add git@github.com:bicycle1885/CellFishing.jl.git

Comment: Use the http protocol, not SSH protocol, so `https://github.com/bicycle1885/CellFishing.jl.git` — the ssh style (`git@github.com:foo/bar.git`) works only if you have an SSH key set up and the public key added to your GitHub account.

Comment: "Julia requested private key location at git@github.com" What _exactly_ did it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you try to install an unregistered package:

```
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.add("CellFishing")
    Updating registry at `c:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.9.3\registries\General.toml`
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * CellFishing (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

The correct way in that case is to use the `url` parameter.

```
Pkg.add(url="https://github.com/bicycle1885/CellFishing.jl")
```